# My refresh-token is returning 401 error in frontend but in my Postman its working but same headers already

Tags: reactjs, jsx, persistence, bearer-token, refresh-token

I'm doing a refresh token for my system I want it when I refresh my browser the state of the system will still be there but when I reload my browser it redirects to the login now I'm doing a refresh-token it giving me the refresh token already but I'm getting a 401 error in my frontend in my postman its like this:

[image: Postman Request]

but in my frontend it gives the token but it reloads to the login page and return a 401 Unauthorized

[image: Frontend Output]

this is my code for this is my AuthController.php

```
 public function refreshToken(Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->user()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    $request->user()->tokens()->delete(); // Revoke all user's tokens

    $remember_token = $request->user()->createToken('remember_token')->plainTextToken;
    $expiresAt = now()->addMinute(30)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    return response()->json([
        'remember_token' => $remember_token,
        'expires_at' => $expiresAt
    ]);
}
```

This is my useRefreshToken hook jsx

```
import axios from '../api/axios';
import useAuth from './useAuth';

const TOKEN_URL = '/api/refresh-token';

const useRefreshToken = () => {
const { auth, setAuth } = useAuth(); // Retrieve auth state and setter

const refresh = async () => {
        const remember_token = localStorage.getItem('remember_token');
        const config = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${remember_token}`
            }
        };
        const response = await axios.get(
            TOKEN_URL,
            config
        )
        localStorage.setItem('remember_token', response.data.remember_token);
        setAuth(prev => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(prev));
            console.log(response.data.remember_token);
            return {
                ...prev,
                role_id: response.data.role_id,
                remember_token: response.data.remember_token
            }
        });
        return response.data.remember_token
}   
return refresh;
};

export default useRefreshToken;
```

and Lastly this is my PersistLogin.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';
import useRefreshToken from '../hooks/useRefreshToken';

const PersistLogin = () => {
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
const refresh = useRefreshToken();
const { auth,setAuth } = useAuth();

useEffect(() => {
const verifyRefreshToken = async () => {
  try{
    const storedToken = localStorage.getItem('remember_token');
    if (storedToken) {
        setAuth(prev => ({ ...prev, remember_token: storedToken }));
        await refresh(); // Use the refresh function to update the token
    }
  }
  catch(err){
    console.error(err);
  }
  finally{
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
}
!auth?.remember_token ? verifyRefreshToken() : setIsLoading(false);
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
console.log(`isLoading: ${isLoading}`)
console.log(`aT:  ${JSON.stringify(auth?.remember_token)}`)
}, [isLoading])

return (
<>
  {isLoading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <Outlet/>}
</>
)

}
export default PersistLogin;
```

Comment: Do you have any type of authentication configured in Postman?

Comment: none i just do is i login and get the token from the login user and paste that token to the Authorization header and bearer value

Comment: So you are passing Authorization information via Postman.  Compare the REQUEST headers of your Postman to the REQUEST headers of the GET call in your browser's NETWORK tab

Comment: When i login in my frontend i see the token of my login auth now when i reload it returns 401 and in the request header of that 401 error in network tab it shows the header of Authorization: Bearer and the token here but why its still 401?